# Can I force scala to error on an inexhaustive match?

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, warnings

An inexhaustive match such as

```
def foo[A](t: Seq[A]) = t match {
    Seq(x) => x
}
```

is often (not always, but usually) a mistake on my part that will crash at runtime. Scala warns, but in an incremental build, the file might already be compiled so I will miss the warning.

Is there a way, either globally or locally, perhaps by an annotation, to force scala to turn the warning into an error?

Comment: I think your example will always emit an error...

Comment: I can't tell if you're asking for -Xfatal-warnings

Comment: @som-snytt ah I did not know about -Xfatal-warnings. That would be a step in the right direction, if there's no way to target this particular warning.

Comment: I wonder why this isn't a compiler error already, though, without having to use `-Xfatal-warnings`.

Comment: @DhruvKapoor Probably a combination of sometimes the compiler can't assess the completeness (when extractors are involved) and incomplete matches can be useful (`x sliding 2 map { case Seq(a, b) => }`)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to supply a custom reporter that arbitrarily reports warnings as errors (or conversely), but the API is currently string-based, so it would filter on string messages and not typed warnings.

There is no built-in way to fail on particular warnings, but `-Xlint -Xfatal-warnings` is the usual way to escalate warnings.

Warning suppression has been requested, but considered dangerous. With fatal warnings, the requirement would be to suppress the warnings that are considered benign.

If you have a residual deprecation, it's possible to suppress the warning (which would fail under -Xfatal-warnings) by invoking it from a deprecated method; if that method is local, it won't generate a warning.

```
scala> @deprecated("","") def f = 8
f: Int

scala> f
<console>:9: warning: method f is deprecated: 
              f
              ^
scala> object A {
     | def a = {
     | @deprecated("","") def _f = f
     | _f
     | }}
defined object A

scala> A.a
res1: Int = 8
```

The local deprecation trick was itself deprecated, but you can still use a forwarding companion:

```
scala> @deprecated("","") def f = 8
f: Int

scala> f
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
res0: Int = 8

scala> @deprecated("","") class C { def g = f }; object C extends C
defined class C
defined object C

scala> C.g
res1: Int = 8
```

Comment: Since then, they "caved" on local warning suppression and added `@nowarn` for local suppression and `-Wconf` for global policy.

Answer (score 0):

Consider asking questions about your build process.

1. You should be doing a full, clean build (not incremental) and running unit tests immediately prior to code commit/check-in.  This to avoid (potential, remaining) bugs in SBT or your build process.  You are, of course, expected to monitor the results for errors and warnings.
2. Are you, or perhaps should you be, doing *Continuous Integration* (automatic, scheduled build/tests)?  During such you may have, or introduce, some control over how warnings are addressed (ignored or trigger build failure/warning).
3. I don't see way to do this from the `scalac` command line.  If all other approaches don't meet your needs then consider as a last resort, and then only if appropriate to your build tooling: create a wrapper script for `scalac`, also named `scalac` that:

   - invokes the true `scalac`
   - monitors output: return error when the particular error is printed, and perhaps delete the target class file [captured from error statement] to further force the issue.