# Bypassing deprecation warnings in Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, scala-2.11, deprecation-warning

There is a nice way to avoid deprecation warnings in Scala 2.10 (and before) by [invoking the deprecated method from a deprecated local def](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499003/can-i-force-scala-to-error-on-an-inexhaustive-match/17506410). Unfortunately, it doesn't work in Scala 2.11. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this Scala issue comment](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7934?focusedCommentId=66403&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-66403), we can define methods calling deprecated API in a deprecated class/trait, and have the companion object to this class extend it without a warning:

```
scala> @deprecated("", "") def foo = 0
foo: Int

scala> object Test { @deprecated("", "") class Coral { def fooForwarder = foo }; object Coral extends Coral }
defined object Test

scala> Test.Coral.fooForwarder
res1: Int = 0
```

Comment: It is not necessary to nest `Coral` in `Test`, just as a side note.

Comment: Now, since you "officially" announced this, I guess no one can get rid of that behavior any more. The bug has become a feature.

Comment: @sschaef 1. This is less "official" than the linked issue comment, given who made it and the ticket being closed specifically due to this workarond. 2. The pre-2.11 workaround linked in the question was removed despite also being mentioned in an SO answer (and making a lot more sense in my opinion). 3. The wrapping in `Test` is just to make them companions in the REPL, `:paste` could be used as well.